# I need to get data between two markers from dataframe by finding the index of those markers first in rstudio

Tags: r

I am loading a csv file and it has data and markers(column names). Anytime person reset the machine which is collecting the data a new marker appears. I am trying to find a solution to first find those markers and with those index only save the data in a different dataframe between those markers. can anyone help.
I have dataframe with column names repeating randomly and I need data between column names.

```
view (df) 435,657,23,23
          23,5,67,78
          v1,v2,v3,v4          
          12,32,454,34
          23,67,45,3
          v1,v2,v3,v4
          43,56,67,88
```

Comment: How have you already tried to solve this problem? What difficulties did you have?

Comment: my data has few markers in it. I have to get the data between the markers. When I am using readlines function it will give me the indexes of those markers but then I don't have dataframe anymore. I am still trying to figure out. I am new to this

Comment: readLines function can read the file with null, spaces, weird characters but then I need to convert it to dataframe for data cleaning

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

```
## read it in as character
df = readLines("your_file.csv")
## remove and save column names
colname_rows = df[grepl("^v1", df)] ## assuming all the column names start with v1
colname_values = unique(df[colname_rows,]) ## you can check that they're all the same
## remove those rows
df = df[!colname_rows, ]
## read the remaining rows as CSV
df = read.table(text = df, sep = ",")
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor, i think the objective is to obtain the data between those two markers or column headers and ignore before and after those markers.

Comment: and the end result will have a new dataframe with the desired data and column headings